# Find constants $a,b$ s.t. the correlation of $X$ and $aX+bY$ is $\rho$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be square integrable and uncorrelated. Let $\rho \in [-1,1]$  Find constants $a,b$ s.t. the correlation of $X$ and $aX+bY$ is $\rho$.

Our professor wrote this problem down and then he immediately came up with $a=\rho$ and $b=\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}$.

However, I am really struggling to come up with this solution. Therefore, I try to reconstruct the steps he made and it would be nice if you could provide me with some guidance.

I know from what is given that $Cov(X,Y)=0$. He also noted that $\sigma_{X}^2=\sigma_{Y}^2=1$ :

Then starting with what i know is that
$$\rho =\frac{Cov(aX+bY,X)}{\sqrt{\sigma_{aX+bY}^2\sigma_{Y}^2}} =    \frac{aCov(X,X)+bCov(Y,X)}{\sqrt{(a^2\sigma_{X}+b^2\sigma_{Y})\sigma_{Y}^2}}      =    \frac{a\sigma_{X}}{\sqrt{(a^2\sigma_{X}+b^2\sigma_{Y})\sigma_{Y}^2}}                $$
Using $\sigma_{X}^2=\sigma_{Y}^2=1$
$$   =   \frac{a}{\sqrt{(a^2+b^2)}}                               $$

Solving this yields 
$$   a^2 = \frac{b^2\rho^2}{(1-\rho^2)}    $$
and 
$$                         b^2= \frac{a^2(1-\rho^2)}{\rho^2}                 $$

where the solutions of the professor obviously would fit. However, is this really the shortest approach deducting all this and then simply guessing that $a=\rho$ and $b=\sqrt{(1-\rho^2)}$ would solve the equations?

Thanks for your input in advance I am a little bit desperate now.

Comment: (Don't be desperate for that !). This is a heuristic proof (you prove and at the same time you discover the result). In the other way (you advise "guessing"... I would have never guessed such a result...), you would give a non-heuristical proof that correspond to the type of questions "check that...".

Comment: Yeah me neither, however, again as you suggested it is a heuristic proof and you go the way I choose, you will only get a result by trying, or as I would say guessing, some values and checking them. Or is there a more sophisticated way?